# Java generics impossible assignment?

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, java-15

Every time I *think* I understand generics better (and can answer without compiling), I get to an example where this theory breaks. Here is a very simple example:

```
static void consumer(List<? super List<String>> param) {
    System.out.println(param);
}
```

And two invocations:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = List.of("123");
    consumer(list);
    consumer(List.of("123"));
}
```

To me, none of the invocations should compile. A `String` is not a supertype of `List`. Still, the second one compiles. But let's suppose that this happens because the compiler could infer *some* type here. Of course such a type does not exist and it will fail at runtime, right? Right? Nope. It just works. As such, can someone bring some sanity to my life please?

Comment: Hmm? You didn't write `List<List<? super String>>`, you wrote `List<? super List<String>>`.

Comment: The compiler could infer the generic parameter of `List.of` as `Object`... (don't know if that's what actually happens though).

Comment: @Sweeper yes, that is the _only_ explanation I had for myself too...

Comment: How did you reach `X extends String implements List`? All the compiler has to do is find a type which satisfies `super List<String>`, and can also be converted from `String` (i.e. a superclass of `String`). And `Object` is found. Why `X extends String implements List`?

Comment: @Sweeper nvm, edited that. But anyway, you actually made me remember of the beautiful `--debug=verboseResolution=all` (and sometimes helpful) option...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah darn!

```
javac  --debug=verboseResolution=all Sandbox.java
```

shows that `consumer(List.of("123"))` is compiled to:

```
instantiated signature: (Object)List<Object>
target-type: List<? super List<String>>
```

Comment: Wow I didn't know I could see exactly how javac thinks about my source code! Learned something new today!

Comment: @Sweeper that isn't a documented option though. it might change (go away) in any release. I randomly upvoted one of your q, after all you made me remember this option.

Comment: A nice one Eugene, +1 for `--debug=verboseResolution=all`. You might want to add some explanation about the findings. I am not sure I can interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a more “*functional*” explanation, you have to consider what `param` is.

By applying [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), notice that it is thus a `List` that is a consumer of `List<String>`.

- Compatible consumers are those which can consume `List<String>` or any of its parent types;
- When applied to `List`, it means a list on which you can call `add()` with any parent type of `List<String>`. A `List<Object>` is thus compatible.

This is why `consumer()` can be called with a `List<Object>` but not a `List<String>` (`String` is not a supertype of `List<String>`).

Since `List.of(…)` can always match `List<Object>` at declaration time, it accepts the second call.

Note that from inside the `consumer()` method, you will never be able to retrieve a `List<String>` from `param` (i.e. use it as a producer). You can only add new ones into it (i.e. use it as a consumer) – and indeed, you can add a `List<String>` into a `List<Object>` (although in this particular case, `List.of()` produces an immutable list, so it will fail at runtime).

Comment: thank you. I pretty much know this, my question was what it is inferred to. It turns out it is rather simple in the end.